# Angularjs: ng-repeat y ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo una tabla que relleno con ng-repeat, en cada fila tengo un botón y quiero que al hacer click sobre él aparezca el segundo ng-if="company.id == idcompany" pero sólo en esa fila y me aparece en todos. ¿Como puedo hacerlo?

```
<tr ng-repeat="company in companiesList">
........
<div ng-if="company.verified == 'false'">
<input type="button" ng-class="classBtnActivar" value="ACTIVAR" ng-click="activateCompany(company.id)">
   <div style="background-color: #d1d1d1; border-radius: 100px;" ng-if="company.id == idcompany">
       <p style="text-align: center">¿Quieres activar todos los comercios de la compañía?</p>
       <div style="text-align: center">
           <input type="button" ng-class="classBtnActivar" value="SI" style="text-align: center">
           <input type="button" ng-class="classBtnActivar" value="NO" style="text-align: center">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como se obtiene el valor de `$scope.idcompany`?

Comment: Lo que quieres es que al presionar "SI" salga "NO" y viceversa?

Comment: $scope.idcompany se obtiene del controlador cuando se pasa por la función ng-click="activateCompany(company.id), ese parámetro se almacena en $scope.idcompany. @devconcept

Comment: No, @CésarGómez lo que quiero es que al presionar el botón ACTIVAR, aparezca el <div> con la pregunta y las dos opciones "SI" y "NO"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero tienes que hacer una variable $scope.fila, que en el mismo método de activateCompany le tienes que pasar la posición, luego comparas. No obstante lo puedes probar sin pasar el id, solo la posición. Espero te funcione.

```
<tr ng-repeat="company in companiesList">
........
<div ng-if="!company.verified">
<input type="button" ng-class="classBtnActivar" value="ACTIVAR" ng-click="activateCompany(company.id, $index)">
<div style="background-color: #d1d1d1; border-radius: 100px;" ng-if="company.id == idcompany && $index == fila">
    <p style="text-align: center">¿Quieres activar todos los comercios de la compañía?</p>
   <div style="text-align: center">
       <input type="button" ng-class="classBtnActivar" value="SI" style="text-align: center">
       <input type="button" ng-class="classBtnActivar" value="NO" style="text-align: center">
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</tr>
```